# Edges of Xubuntu desktop are cut off on my Sony TV?

Tags: display, hdmi, display-resolution, overscan

I installed Xubuntu and it seems to work fine, with one exception. It identified my 55" Sony TV as a 37" Sony.

Normally I wouldn't care except I can't set it to `1920x1080` resolution without the edges of the desktop getting cut off.

When I enter full-screen mode I can't see the menu bar and parts of the application windows. I tried playing with `xrandr`, but I don't really know how to use it...

For what it's worth, it's connected to my Intel NUC via HDMI.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Most TV's have overscan enabled by default; see if you can disable it in the TV's onboard menu.

> Overscan is a behavior in certain television sets, in which part of
>   the input picture is shown outside of the visible bounds of the
>   screen. It exists because cathode-ray tube (CRT) television sets from
>   the 1930s through to the early 2000s were highly variable in how the
>   video image was positioned within the borders of the screen.
>
> Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overscan)

If overscan is enabled, this will happen, which is exactly what you've described:

[image]

Comment: On my Sony TV, I had to set Settings -> Screen -> Display Area to "Full Pixel"

Comment: On my Panasonic TV, the issue got resolved by turning off the overscan mode exactly as mentioned by @You'reAGitForNotUsingGit